# Alternative to high Watt resistor terminating resistor

Tags: termination, power-dissipation, rs422

In the following circuit a 120 ohm termination resistor is placed across the Rx+ and Rx- data lines connected to a RS485/422 transceiver. The transceiver is protected up +/- 60V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz65zN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want voltage protection on these lines up to 24V. This would mean a user could possibly connect 24V directly across the 120 ohm resistor resulting in 4.8 Watts power disapation. Safe design practice would be to add at least around 50% tolerance to my resistor meaning a need a resistor rated around 7W.

Based on my searching a 7W resistor means moving to a large through hole part. The board space I have is very limited and this is undesirable.

Is there any alternatives to this problem?

Comment: Why not a PTC terminator?

Answer (score 2):

You could AC-terminate the pair, as described in [this application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla070d/slla070d.pdf), but take care to read the caveats.

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla070d/slla070d.pdf]

@Ignacio's suggestion of using a polyfuse as part of the termination resistor might be a better general solution.

Comment: The poly fuse is a nice idea...(but I always feel like I'm walking a tight rope when trying to design one in.)  Maybe one of those zener polyfuse combo's.. I've used one for an over voltage fault protect and it seemed OK.

Comment: Oops.. You'd need two back to back zeners, you don't want to short the signal. :^)

Comment: There are Bi directional TVS diodes for such voltages.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm a little apprehensive about the limited data speeds but still a helpful answer and thanks for the link to a great reference document.